# Table sizing and formatting

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table but I face a few predicaments. The code I have written is so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0, 85, 128}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{255, 85, 128}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{document}



\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AABBED}} p{2cm}}

\arrayrulecolor{mycolor1}

\begin{tabular}{ |s|p{1.3cm}|p{1.3cm}||p{1.3cm}||p{1.3cm}||p{1.3cm}||p{1.3cm}| }

    \hline
    \rowcolor{mycolor} \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Country List} \\
    \hline
    Authors&Energy Efficient&Network Efficient&Performance Increase&Power Efficient&Workload Balancing\\
    \hline
    Afghanistan & AF &AFG&A&b&c \\
%   \rowcolor{gray}
    Aland Islands & AX & ALA&A&b&c  \\
    Albania   &AL & ALB&A&b&c  \\
    Algeria  &DZ & DZA&A&b&c  \\
    American Samoa & AS & ASM&A&b&c  \\
    Andorra & AD & AND&A&b&c \\%\cellcolor[HTML]{AA0044} AND    \\
    Angola & AO & AGO&A&b&c  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which results in the follwing:
[image]

I want to make the following changes:

1. Resize the table in such a way that it is just in the middle of the page
2. Double column separator line. It should be single like the rest of the table, see figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main suggestions:

- To make the table fit inside the width of the textblock, (a) use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment and (b) prefix a `\noindent` instruction to the `tabularx` environment.
- To avoid getting double vertical lines, change all instances of `||` to `|`.

Some further suggestions:

- Center the entries in the five (not six) data columns.
- Allow hyphenation of long words in the header cells.
- Your settings for the parameters `\arraystretch` and `\tabcolsep` seem overly generous. Smaller values work better, I'd say.

These suggestions are implemented in the following, revised version of your code.

[image]

The color you've chosen for the header row that contains the words "Country List" definitely seems to dark. I have no idea what color schemes you are allowed (or required) to implement, but I trust you'll manage to come up with a color for the header row that makes it easier to read the words "Country List".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0, 85, 128}    % maybe too dark?
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{255, 85, 128}
\arrayrulecolor{mycolor1}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}     % 18pt seems extravagant
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % 2.5 seems excessive

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AABBED}\raggedright}p{2cm}}

\begin{document}

\noindent % <-- important
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |s| *{5}{C|} }
\hline
    \rowcolor{mycolor} \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Country List} \\
\hline
   Authors & Energy Efficient & Network Efficient & Performance Increase
   & Power Efficient & Workload Balancing\\
\hline
    Afghanistan    & AF &AFG&A&b&c \\
    %   \rowcolor{gray}
    Aland Islands  & AX & ALA&A&b&c  \\
    Albania        & AL & ALB&A&b&c  \\
    Algeria        & DZ & DZA&A&b&c  \\
    American Samoa & AS & ASM&A&b&c  \\
    Andorra        & AD & AND&A&b&c \\%\cellcolor[HTML]{AA0044} AND    \\
    Angola         & AO & AGO&A&b&c  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have physical constraints, text width and size of each box around each letter + empty space padding.

Anyway, to get started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0, 85, 128}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{255, 85, 128}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{document}



\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AABBED}} p{2cm}}

\arrayrulecolor{mycolor1}


\begin{tabular}{ |s|p{.06\textwidth}|p{.06\textwidth}|p{.06\textwidth}|p{.06\textwidth}|p{.06\textwidth}|p{.06\textwidth}| }

    \hline
    \rowcolor{mycolor} \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Country List} \\
    \hline
    Authors&Energy Efficient&Network Efficient&Performance Increase&Power Efficient&Workload Balancing\\
    \hline
    Afghanistan & AF &AFG&A&b&c \\
%   \rowcolor{gray}
    Aland Islands & AX & ALA&A&b&c  \\
    Albania   &AL & ALB&A&b&c  \\
    Algeria  &DZ & DZA&A&b&c  \\
    American Samoa & AS & ASM&A&b&c  \\
    Andorra & AD & AND&A&b&c \\%\cellcolor[HTML]{AA0044} AND    \\
    Angola & AO & AGO&A&b&c  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does your code ensure that the tabular material fits inside the width of the textblock?

Comment: Your answer is correct  and there is no mistake at all. but I had to mark @Mico right because his is the one I want.

Comment: Yea totally! Mico‘s answer makes mine look weak. I whipped it up on the train (hence -to get started-). :) I can add some tips later anyway for posterity, because I used to have these problems.